# Rewrite url with htaccess error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I am trying to rewrite this url:

**`news?post=title`**

to

**`news/title`**

This is what i have been trying

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.$ /news?post=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You seem to have multiple things going on here. Is it _just_ the `news/title` rewrite you want to do, or are you trying to accomplish other things too? By the way, you are rewriting `news/title` to `news?post=title`, not the other way around. `news/title` is the link your pages produce, and what is seen (and bookmarked/indexed) by visitors and bots.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^news/([a-z]+)?$ news?post=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: so answer is useful for you?

Comment: He may not have enough points to accept it. By the way, your rewrite rule is wrong -- you don't want to make the title field optional, you want to make a trailing / optional: `...-z]+)/?$`

Comment: this is only clue so need to change according your need